# Lucee 5.0 websocket outside localhost

Tags: tomcat, websocket, coldfusion, lucee

Hey everybody reading this,

Lately I'm busy researching websockets and in particularly websockets in Lucee. I had some difficulties installing it through the admin menu (solution: update lucee to the latest version -_-) after that the extension was successfully installed.

The second thing I tried was to implement the most simple example of websockets found here: https://github.com/isapir/lucee-websocket/wiki/Example---Echo. He also made a video explaining his steps. I ran into some connection issue's and after some hours I got something working.

First let me tell you what the configuration is: I'm working on a windows server 2012 R2 and here is Lucee successfully running. Some websites are configured in IIS and everything is working perfect. In case of the websockets I successfully ran a console test through IE on the server with localhost. I could send a message and receive it. I used the url: ws://localhost:8888/ws/echo (as in the example).

Now the problem I'm having is that I want to do the same externally. Of course you cannot use localhost then so I tried every combination possible, but every time it says something like "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" or "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" etc.

What I think is that the websocket extension is working like it should, but the connection is refused by IIS or Tomcat. Therefore I also installed websocket support in IIS, enabled it, but still nothing.

Can somebody point me in the right direction why this is happening? Is it something with a port, or a setting in tomcat. I'm  not really good at this stuff, I'm happier just programming applications. Hopefully somebody can help.

You also have a test application here: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html but this is not working for my url.

PS: I also need to use a VPN to connect to the server. Is this something to consider?

Thanks,

Roland

**EDIT**

Let me give you an update. First let me state that, like I said, we already have websites working on an open domain through IIS. These are working excellent externally. Now when I try to connect to the websocket through an open domain with the port 80, I get a 404 error. When I try it with port 8888 then It gives the following response:

> WebSocket Error: Network Error 12029, A connection with the server could not be established

If I get the 404 this is the response:
[image]

But I'm probably not the only one who wants to have websockets working outside localhost. For instance how can I get this working on port 80? That would be better instead of opening other ports.

Hopefully somebody can help me, thanks!

Comment: Take one step at a time. `localhost:8888` is using Tomcat, not IIS (unless you have changed IIS default port of 80 which I doubt). Next get a normal CFM page to work using IIS over port 80 from your network or ColdFusion server.  Try `localhost:80`. Until that works there is no point trying externally. [Maybe this will help](http://blog.simplicityweb.co.uk/105/manually-connecting-lucee-to-an-iis-website)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, yea I didn't install the server myself so I don't have a clear idea what is installed. But I will check if I can run the same test on port 80 on localhost, also gonna check what settings IIS uses. If I have an anwser or another problem I will check it back to this page, thanks again.